Узнать, что вызываемая программа выдала ошибку
subprocess.run('ffmpeg ***', shell=True)

Применяю subprocess, для выполнения команд, вызова программ.
Если к примеру ffmpeg выдает ошибку. Как определить, что входе выполнения произошла ошибка и достать этот самый текст ошибки?
Не работает
result = sub.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input', '-c:v', 'libaom-av1', '-b:v', '500K', '-aom-params', 'tune=psnr:enable-tpl-model=1', '/output.mp4'], stdout=sub.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
print(result.stdout)


Ошибки обычно выводятся в stderr, так что смотрите result.stderr, а не stdout

Кстати, пробовали python-ffmpeg?

Это консольная утилита? Я просто не хочу это выяснять, устанавливая это приложение из каменного века. Если да, то оно "всё расскажет", выводя свои результаты в консоль. Не нравится использование консоли? Ну, возможен и такой вариант: перенаправить вывод в файл, а уже потом загрузить его на просмотр в Питон.

import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    try:
        # Запускаем команду, сохраняя стандартный вывод и стандартный поток ошибок
        result = subprocess.run(
            command, 
            shell=True, 
            text=True, 
            capture_output=True,  # захватываем stdout и stderr
            check=True  # выбросить исключение при ошибке
        )
        # Выводим результат работы команды
        print("Output:", result.stdout)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        # Если команда завершилась с ошибкой, получаем текст ошибки
        print("Error:", e.stderr)

# Пример использования
command = "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4"  # Замени на свою команду
run_command(command)


Или я что то наделал или... Как сделать так, чтобы прогресс выполнения отображался в консоле? Сейчас мучаюсь с encoding. Что то с кодировкой....
